# How to create a safe C interface for LUA

Tags: c, lua, swig

Im researching about how to integrate full script support inside my app but have a bit of a problem planning my C API to be LUA friendly.

Basically I got bunch of structs that are created through init and free 
functions like this:

[ test.h ]

```
typedef struct
{
char name[ 50 ];
} Test;


Test *TestAdd( char *name );

Test *TestDelete( Test *test );
```

[ test.c ]

```
Test *TestAdd( char *name )
{
Test *test = ( Test * ) calloc( 1, sizeof( Test ) );

strcpy( test->name, name );

return test;
}


Test *TestDelete( Test *test )
{
free( test );
return NULL;
}
```

Im using swig to generate the LUA module so I create the following interface file:

[ test.i ]

```
%module test
%{

%}

Test *TestAdd( char *name );

Test *TestDelete( Test * test );
```

Everything work fine if the user code is like this:

```
a = test.TestAdd( "test" )
a = test.TestDelete( a )

if( a != nil ) print( a.name )
```

But if the user code is like that:

```
a = test.TestAdd( "test" )
test.TestDelete( a )

if( a != nil ) print( a.name ) -- Crash the app with bad_access (not just a LuaVM error).
```

Or even worst:

```
a = test.TestAdd( "test" )
test.TestDelete( a )
test.TestDelete( a )
-- Another way of making crash my app completely!
```

Is there any way that I can create a set of API in C that would avoid this kind of problem and would allow the user to safely add/delete and access properties in a safe way that would not create "bad access" error and make the whole program crash, the best would be that the LUAVM simply return an error and the execution continue.

I've been searching and tried different approach to my C API to avoid this problem but failed…

Anybody can help me or give me some pointers about the direction to go with this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you can set the pointer to `NULL` then `free`ing it twice won't be a problem and you just need to check if it's `NULL` in each function that uses it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this: stop exporting C-style interfaces directly to Lua. C is not Lua, and you should never intend for Lua programs to act like C programs.

Unless there is no way to avoid it, Lua code should never have to free anything. If Lua code explicitly creates something, then Lua code should have governance over its lifetime. That means you use garbage collection to delete the memory: when the Lua GC is finished with it, you use a metamethod to free the pointer with whatever call you use.

In general, you give Lua a pointer to an object in one of two ways: either Lua *owns* that pointer, or that pointer is to an object that will outlive the `lua_State` itself (and therefore will always be available to the Lua script). There are occasions where you might hand Lua some temporary object that it can reference, but these should be avoided whenever possible.

What you need to do is [use the `%newobject` directive](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Customization.html#Customization_ownership) to tell SWIG that `TestAdd` returns a pointer that needs to be deleted. Then, you need to associate the `Test` object with `TestDelete` as the deleter, [using %newfree typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn34). This will properly transfer ownership of the `Test` from C to Lua. At which point, C should *never* delete it manually. Just let Lua and SWIG do their job.

As such, `TestDelete` should not be exposed to Lua directly. It will be called implicitly when the GC detects that nobody is referring to the `Test` instance anymore.

Comment: Hummm Im not sure Im getting it, can you create a simple example with the code I post above? From the page you redirect me I feel that:

   %newobject create_foo;
   %delobject destroy_foo;
   ...
   Foo *create_foo();
   void destroy_foo(Foo *foo);

Would be the way to go no? But I still don't know I can I implement this...

Comment: @McBob: Sorry about the links; I've corrected them. But no, as I said, *do not expose `TestDelete` to the user*. I don't know what part you're not getting, since the SWIG documentation is pretty comprehensive. If you don't understand how SWIG typemaps and options work, you should figure that out first.